# RNN optimization for bigger datasets

Tags: optimization, recurrent-neural-network, hyperparameter, tensorflow

I am training bi-directional RNN model with attention for answer selection referring [this](https://github.com/allenai/bi-att-flow/tree/tqa). I am attaching screenshot of tensorflow graphs. My dataset consist of Question and 5 multiple choice sentences as answer and i.e. 39000 question and answers.

```
learning_rate - 0.1
hidden_size - 200
batch_size - 20
n_epoch - 12
n_steps - 20000
n_words - 67000
```

I tried same model on 250 queries with only change in learning rate and model trained with 80% accuracy before overfitting.

```
learning_rate - 0.01
n_words - 699
```

**Observation:** As 250 queries had only 699 words it trained well (as dataset was only related to single topic number of words were less) but 250 queries with 6000 words needs different parameters and same model could not learn so I increased my dataset. Any theory which i should refer and update parameters to train bigger model.

[image: Tensorflow Dev Train Loss & Acc]